# GetHashCode() from booleans only

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, hashcode

I have an immutable class whose only field is a `bool[]` (size determined at runtime).

How can I compute a good hash code of this class? Generally I would just call `GetHashCode()` on each field, and combine them with one of these operators: `+ | &`, but since the only possible hash codes are `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`, that's not really going to get me anywhere. My implementation needs to work with only `bools`, and must work for an arbitrary-sized array.

(Probably doesn't matter much, but I'm coding in C#/.NET.)

Comment: have you considered `BitArray` or depending on size `BitVector32`? That would require less implementation like `GetHashCode` and the like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your `bool[]` is named `bools`:

```
unchecked { 
    int hash = 17;
    for(int index = 0; index < bools.Length; index++) {
        hash = hash * 23 + bools[index].GetHashCode();
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the numbers please Jason? Where did 17 and 23 come from? :-)

Comment: @Jamie Dixon: This is kind of a standard implementation; the key point is that the multiplier is a prime. I think Java's `String.getHashCode` is something very similar.

Comment: this won't work, arrays with same elements in different positions will give the same hashcode

Comment: @mcarbal: First, it doesn't. Consider `{ false, true }` and `{ true, false }`. The first will give the hash code of 23 * (23 * 17 + 0) + 1. The second will give the hash code of 23 * (23 * 17 + 1) + 0. Note that these are different values. Even if all the values are `false`, it will still produce a distinct hash code (`Math.Pow(23, bools.Length) * 17`). Second, you can not expect distinct hash codes for distinct arrays. There are more arrays (`Math.Pow(2, Int32.Max)`) than there are hash codes (`Int32.Max - Int32.Min + 1`). Collisions have to happen. So, what do you mean "won't work?"

Comment: @Jamie, using of non-trivial prime numbers minimizes the probability of collisions in simple cases. For example, 2 as multiplier would collide arrays of 1 false and 33 falses.